# how to compare two image using mingw64 gcc/g++?

Tags: c++, opencv, gcc, g++, mingw

I need compare two image using mingw64 gcc/g++.

I tried https://github.com/huihut/OpenCV-MinGW-Build
but not compiled my source code.

```
test.cpp:1:9: fatal error: opencv2/core/core.hpp: No such file or directory
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

how to compile and compare two image using mingw64 gcc/g++?

Comment: How do you build your project? Did you add all dependencies to opencv? You posted a compiler error regarding missing headers. If the headers are installed on your system you have to add the include path to your project.

Answer (score 0):

First thing: you cant do such tasks with "MinGW gcc/g++" this is only a compiler. What you ment is hor to do such thing with `C` or `C++` which are programming languages.

You already found a project yourself but there are some dependencies you dont have in your posted message it is OpenCV have a look at their [Release page](https://opencv.org/releases/) their also seem to be some precompiled windows binaries. Install this library and try again and see if you got all dependencies. Or better: always read the readmes often they tell what you need to build the projekt.